# Any reason to wrap transaction or include locking hint for single operation stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions, locking

SQL Server 2022

For a stored procedure that contains only a single DML operation (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) :

1. Is there ever any reason to wrap the operation in a transaction?
2. Is there ever any reason to include a locking hint (`ROWLOCK`, `UPDLOCK`, etc.)

Here's an (artificial ) example :

```
USE [CarShop]
GO

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAutoForCustomer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAutoForCustomer]
    @autoMake nvarchar(50), 
    @autoModel nvarchar(50), 
    @autoYear int,
    @customerNameFirst nvarchar(50),
    @customerNameLast nvarchar(50),
    @autoId bigint output
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @customerId bigint 

SELECT @customerId = c.[Id]
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
WHERE c.[NameFirst] = @customerNameFirst
AND c.[NameLast] = @customerNameLast

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Auto]
           ([CustomerId]
            [Make]
           ,[Model]
           ,[Year])
     VALUES
           (@customerId
           ,@autoMake
           ,@autoModel
           ,@autoYear)


SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
GO
```

Does SQL Server automatically (1) force atomicity across all SQL statements in the procedure, and (2) lock both [Customer] and [Auto] ( at relevant level row/page/table ) for duration of execution of all statements ?

Or is it necessary to wrap the procedure ( all three statements : SELECT , UPDATE , SELECT ) in a transaction to ensure that customer is row still present at time of insert auto, and auto is still present at time of set output to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ?

EDIT : Ok as pointed out in comments the correct way to do this is condense to single line of SQL that is executed atomically by SQL Server Engine :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Auto]
           ([CustomerId]
            [Make]
           ,[Model]
           ,[Year])
SELECT [Id] AS [CustomerId]
      ,@autoMake AS [Make]
      ,@autoModel AS [Model]
      ,@autoYear AS [Year]
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE [NameFirst] = @customerNameFirst
AND [NameLast] = @customerNameLast
```

Comment: What have you concluded from your research? You only have to read the definition of the things you are asking about to answer that yourself.

Comment: My reading indicates that there is never any reason for transaction or lock hint.  But I know relatively very little about MS SQL Server compared with the experts.

Comment: Never is not correct, not in your scenario maybe.

Comment: If you take the definition of a transaction "A database transaction, by definition, must be atomic (it must either be complete in its entirety or have no effect whatsoever" then you can imagine it has no relevance to a single statement, its only of interest with multiple statements - to have an all or nothing effect.

Comment: And any research of locking should throw up that you should avoid using locking hints unless you face an issue for which they are the solution. If you don't yet have an issue then ignore them.

Comment: That's what I thought. But definitely seems there's a lot of t-sql out there where people cavalierly throw in transactions and lock hints in hopes it serves as a sort of magic elixir. 

When I said "never" above I was referring to stored procedure with single DML operation.

Comment: I appended an example to my post - just to make my concern absolutely clear.

Comment: For a start, combine your queries, there is no need for 2, use the select as part of your insert, and insert from select, rather than insert from values.